# Getting started at 3D modelling and animation

Tags: 3d, animation, models

I'm looking for  book or a guide that will direct me to 3D modelling/animation for gaming.  Most tutorials will go for lengths about things I don't really need for games and I want to get to the chops of making assets for my games -- like many developers have said: the best way to get experience is finish a game!

So what good books/tutorials are there on modelling for games?

Comment: What things do you think you "don't need for games?" It's dangerous to make such assumptions about a field you admittedly don't know that much about.

Comment: Removed the backstory since it isn't pertinent.

Answer (score 5):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org)'s site has a lot of [decent documentation and tutorials](http://www.blender.org/education-help/).

Comment: To be honest, I would say that there are not that many tutorials on Blender's site. Its better to go to places like blenderartists.org for blender tutorials.

Blender cookie may also be a good option http://www.blendercookie.com/

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the *Josh Petrie's* recommendation of using Blender tutorials. Blender is a great free tool and those tutorials can't be useless even if they do not focus on modeling and animation for games.

---

But as you asked for 3D modeling/animation for *games*, I recommend you to search for **low polygon** 3D or modeling informations, which is the type of 3D modeling often used in video games.

Here is an interesting website, where you can see a professional at work in videos (with explanations) and read some interesting text tutorials about 3D modeling for video games (partially):
http://poopinmymouth.com/tutorial/tutorial.htm

And, If you are really a beginner, I recommend its very old but still interesting tutorial *Character Modeling for Game Design*:
http://poopinmymouth.com/process/character_tutorial/character_process.htm

Comment: That site... is actually legit o_O

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I have personally read and recommend:
[http://www.amazon.com/Game-Artists-Guide-Maya/dp/0782143768/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1306115253&sr=8-6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0782143768)

Note however that this book is about Maya and is specific to character art. If you want to learn on a different 3D tool and are more interested in environment art, well then you need to specify that.

(There are also a few other books about game art by that same author listed on that page. I haven't personally read any of the others, but having the same author is a good sign.)